# multiple parsers using C++ api in bison, conflicts with stack.hh

Tags: c++, parsing, bison

When you run bison, it creates a stack class for you in "stack.hh". The file name is fixed, but the contents are wrapped in a namespace of your choosing.

If you use bison to generate 2 separate grammars (ie 2 *.y files) and you use the C++ mode, the "stack.hh" files conflict and get overwritten.

A similar thing happens for the "location.hh" and "position.hh" classes that are autogenerated, but there is a work around in bison 2.7

```
%define api.location.type "foo::location"
```

that lets you reuse the `foo` grammar namespace in your `bar` grammar namespace.

But I can't find anyway of doing this exercise when dealing with the "stack.hh" file.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to deal with this is just to put the Bison files in two separate directories.  Then when you generate the code the files will not conflict, assuming each set of files gets generated in the same location as the corresponding Bison file.

Comment: I'm facing OP's problem as well. The actual problem is regarding including more than one parser. They'll all generate a parser.h which relies on location.h, stack.h and position.h being included directly. When you compile a project that needs all of them then you'll face the problem of having more than one "stack.h" (and others) in the same include space.